# Is there any open-source solution to scanning / decoding GSM/UMTS traffic?

Tags: software-defined-radio

I want to build a passive (rx-only) scanner to listen to GSM and UMTS traffic. I am not interested in breaking encryption or anything like that - but more interested in collecting statistics and such.

Things like numbers of RACH bursts. Number of active calls on a cell/frequency/channel.

I found some things online - like OpenBTS and OpenBTS-UMTS. There are great, but the appear to be only intended to emulate and Basestation/ENodeB. I am looking for somthing a bit more generic - which can just analyse channels (e.g. in GSM scan all the common control channels and look for RACH bursts and assignment commands).

Is there anything like this out there? - Or can OpenBTS/OpenBTS-UMTS be made to do this?

I have an Ettus USRP to get started with.... not really sure I want to write a stack my-self!

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic because it is asking about working with a specific radio service which is not amateur radio (and unlike [your other question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/why-bother-to-have-a-high-power-base-station-when-mobile-units-are-generally-low) it doesn't generalize). Sorry!

Comment: awwww.....poo : )    .... you think I can re-word it? Does amateur radio not cover Telecomms?

Comment: In principle, someone could be using the GSM protocol on amateur radio bands under amateur radio licensing. In practice, it's not done.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO - ah, great - lets go with that : )   (ok fair point, I'll look for another forum!)

Comment: @code_fodder After searching earlier, I don't think there's any relevant site here on SE. Google is your friend, hopefully. :-)